# How to install Ubuntu 14.10 on an Asus Z87-Deluxe motherboard

Tags: system-installation

I have tried turning off Secure Boot, Fastboot, & CSM. But everything I try doesn't work.

I built my computer with the Asus Z87-Deluxe motherboard. I have Windows 7 64bit installed with no problems. I was having problems getting Ubuntu 14.04 loaded. I found that problem a couple of hours ago. I discovered that Linux won't work with ASMedia SATA.

Both of my DVD drives were plugged into those ports. Moving them to the Intel Z87 SATA allows Ubuntu to install. But it does not see the Windows 7 OS. And it can't set up the boot loader.

Comment: Can you please state in more detail what is the problem you are having, how you are installing and all.

Comment: Please also include any error messages you are having

Comment: And also, is it a single boot or a dual boot and if there is an existing OS what is the existing OS?